# Wondering the proper grammar for "is" or "are"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I'm hoping to learn the proper grammar for a question I just asked a colleague.

> 1. The first of two calipers shipped to us is here.
> 2. The first of two calipers shipped to us are here.

Comment: This is a common question asked of English native speakers to test their ability to match subject to verb.  The subject is "the first", which is singular, so it should be **is**.  It's also a common question on this site, so you're likely to find many duplicate questions if you search for "subject verb agreement"

Comment: @Andrew Should it be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @Tashus  I don't know how others do it, but I have the hardest time finding duplicates on SE.  For some reason every search pulls up any number of unrelated hits.  There must be a trick to it.  Fortunately this one was pretty easy, but I suggest Jocelyn do the search herself in case the one I linked doesn't help.  There are many, many others.

Comment: You wouldn't say *The first of my three children **are** named Mary.*  right?

Comment: @Andrew I also find the interface difficult. Usually I search for a similar question in another tab, then type the exact title into the VTC interface. I have not had much luck using what I assume should be the intended workflow. (I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate though. The subtle difference between a plural as part of the noun phrase and a plural in the predicate makes me think that these are distinct.)

Comment: I think this question is potentially confusing simply because the particular noun ***caliper*** is often pluralised when referring to a ***single*** instrument (somewhat like ***scissors***). Which actually shouldn't have any relevance to the issue being queried, so perhaps it would have been better to ask about *The first of two **instruments** shipped to us.*

Comment: @Andrew I've added a place for folks to share their [searching tips](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4788#4788) to the Contributor's Guide on [meta]. This is why it's really important to tag things properly - you can use tags to limit your search AND they affect what shows up in the "Related" section in the side bar...

Answer (score 4):

Here you should say:

> The first of two calipers shipped to us **is** here.

Two calipers exist, but the subject of the sentence is only *the first* (caliper). Since this is only a single caliper, the singular verb "is" should be used.

Comment: You can ignore everything after the "of". The real subject is "The first", which is singular.

Comment: @DoubleU Do you understand my answer to mean something other than what you have written?

Comment: I am just proposing an easier way to interpret the sentence.